# An explanation of an ANTLR syntax required for JSON grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, lexical-analysis

At the moment I'm investigating the JSON ANTLR grammar from ANTLR project wiki: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/JSON+Interpreter

```
String  :
    '"' ( EscapeSequence | ~('\u0000'..'\u001f' | '\\' | '\"' ) )* '"'
    ;

fragment EscapeSequence
        :   '\\' (UnicodeEscape |'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
        ;
```

What I cannot get is why they negate `\\` and `\"` in the `String` rule? It will be matched by a `EscapeSequence` anyway.

If we change it to `~('\u0000'..'\u001f')` then it should mean the same.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This serves for disallowing single unescaped backslashes and single unescaped double quotes. Note that these appear as `'\\'` and `'\"'`, because at least the former is disallowed in the grammar literal as well.

The EscapeSequence rule in contrast allows escaped backslashes and double quotes.

Omitting the exclusion of a single unescaped double quote would extend String tokenization to the last quote that can be found, however it should terminate at the first unescaped quote.

Omitting the exclusion of a single unescaped backslash would allow sequences beginning with a backslash, that are not supported EscapeSequences.

Comment: Oh, I see `EscapeSequence` allows `\\\\`, while `String` disallows `\\`. Right?

Comment: I think you got it, though your comment formatting went wrong.

Comment: Oh :-S It's because of SO treaded backslash to be escape backtick. Ok, thanks